# How to get sum of value with where condition after group relationship table Laravel PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Any method to get a sum of values in the relationship database query in laravel. I have two data tables, one is a stock and the other is a stock update. I want to get records and group those according to some id like paper_id. The stock_update table has a quality field. I want the sum of value that quality such as A quality has 500, B quality has 300 like.

//Model

```
 public function paperstocks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(paper_stock_update::class, 'paper_stocks_id', 'id');
    }
```

//Livewire Component

```
 $this->dry = paper_stock::with('paperstocks','paper')->groupBy('paper_id')->get();
```

//Laravel Blade

```
@foreach ($dry as $item)

<tr>
 <td>
  @php
   $qualityA = $item->paperstocks->where('quality', 'A')->sum('qty');
  @endphp

  {{ $qualityA }}
 </td>

 <td>
  @php
   $qualityB = $item->paperstocks->where('quality', 'B')->sum('qty');
  @endphp

  {{ $qualityB }}
 </td>

</tr>

@endforeach
```

{{ $qualityA }} this records working but {{ $qualityB }} this is not working.

Comment: Within the second `<td>`, you're still assigning to `$qualityA` not `$qualityB`.

Comment: Sorry, this is my mistake in writing the equation. it should $qualityB. I found a reason but I still can't solve that. I think the reason for that grouping.